# Correlation Feature Selection and understanding why the covariates were chosen

Tags: r, correlation, feature-selection, prediction

I'm developing a statistical model using [Correlation Feature Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection#Correlation_feature_selection) (CFS).

**Does anybody know how I might produce something where I can understand exactly why one feature was chosen over another?** I can't find any options in FSelector or R/Weka to get this out, but I also don't know if I'm missing some concept about how CFS operates whereby such an output shouldn't be expected.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for letting me know that this if off-topic. I am unsure about the reason for off-topic. Is this question more appropriate for Stackoverflow? I couldn't find an answer in the support links or searching on either site so I'm a little lost as to the problem. It'd be great to understand  the issue so I can ensure more appropriate targeting in the future.

Comment: Questions about how R / an R package / R functions work are off topic here. If you have a statistical question, you should clarify that.

Comment: Ah, I see. I believe that CFS isn't solely an R function but is a known statistical technique employed in other packages too. I'll clarify my question. Thank you!

Comment: This question now seems on topic to me. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance - it was really helpful as the 'off-topic' description offered above was written in a way that I couldn't decode as to the exact issue!